# C++ - Unable to declare static function in .cpp file

Tags: c++

Here is my `GameObject.h`:

```
class GAME_API  GameObject : public WorldObject {
public:
    explicit GameObject();
    ~GameObject();

    static GameObject* CreateGameObject(uint32 entry, Map* map, Position const& pos, QuaternionData const& rotation, uint32 animProgress, GOState goState, uint32 artKit = 0);    

};
```

Here is my `GameObject.cpp`:

```
#include "GameObject.h"
#include "World/Globals/ObjectManager.h"
#include <G3D/Box.h>
#include <G3D/CoordinateFrame.h>
#include <G3D/Quat.h>
#include "Logging/Log.h"

GameObject* GameObject::CreateGameObject(uint32 entry, Map *map, const Position &pos, const QuaternionData &rotation, uint32 animProgress, GOState goState, uint32 artKit /*= 0*/)
{
    GameObjectTemplate const* goInfo = sObjectMgr->GetGameObjectTemplate(entry);
    if (!goInfo)
        return nullptr;

    GameObject* go = new GameObject();
    if (!go->Create(entry, map, pos, rotation, animProgress, goState, artKit, false, 0))
    {
        delete go;
        return nullptr;
    }

    return go;
}
```

The code does not compile giving the following error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "__ZN10GameObjectC1Ev", referenced from:
      __ZN10GameObject16CreateGameObjectEjP3MapRK8PositionRK14QuaternionDataj7GOStatej in GameObject.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: *** [bin/WorldServer] Error 1
make[2]: *** [Source/WorldServer/CMakeFiles/WorldServer.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [Source/WorldServer/CMakeFiles/WorldServer.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [WorldServer] Error 2
```

I am hundred percent sure the problem is with function `CreateGameObject` .

If I remove the declaration from `GameObject.h` and the declaration of `GameObject.cpp` for `CreateGameObject`  function my code compiles.

How Can I resolve this issue ?

I tried placing the declaration inside the header file, still no compilation.

Comment: You can't compile TC on ARM.

Comment: From the error message, the code does compile. It fails to link. According to [the demangler](https://demangler.com/) the missing symbol is `GameObject::GameObject()`. You never defined the constructor.